# How can I hide navigation bar through CAAnimation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, caanimation

Actually For show/hide I am using UIView Animation.
And Simple methods like animated : YES/NO.
But it does not give me smooth response..
Please give me suggestions...

```
BOOL navBarState = [self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden];


    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];


    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!navBarState animated:NO];


    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

It is not giving me satisfactory result I want to do the same thing with CAAnimation..

Comment: Please show us code of what you have tried and what you are currently doing. Your questions is very vague without any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to place the following line into UIView animation braces:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!navBarState animated:NO];
```

Why not just call it with animated:YES without calls to [UIView beginAnimation]/[UIView commitAnimation]?

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:!navBarState animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    rect.origin.y = rect.origin.y < 0 ?
    rect.origin.y + rect.size.height
    :   rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = rect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Just use above code which may help you to get smooth animation...